# Build, compile javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, requirejs, amd

I got a javascript library which currently uses requirejs.

To keep things readable I have structered everything into directories.
I would now like to compile all modules together into one javascript file for production but make the files still workable without compilation for developing so that I do not have to recompile everything when I test something.

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: What problems did you run into while attempting this?

Comment: @Asad I cannot use r.js for this task. I looked how jquery is built (with node.js) which will cost the ability to allow developement withouth recompiling altime

Comment: kyrogen, it would help if you be more specific about the problem you're running into. RequireJS doesn't require you to compile your files during development nor do other libraries like jQuery. Are you getting an error? Is one of the files not loading?

Comment: @Aaronius The problem about requireJs is that it is difficult to use different, independent requirejs projects sidebyside...

Comment: I do almost the same thing, but I dev compile with the optimize=none flag set. Compile times are pretty fast then.

Comment: @bodokaiser have you thought of using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)?